# as3 tracking number value of variables

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, variables

I have a bunch an as3 game going.
In my game when newCrag hits egg_mc the score gets added.

```
// Add the score
var newScore:score_mc;
newScore = new score_mc();
addChild(newScore);
newScore.x = 20;
newScore.y = 20;
newScore.score_txt.text='0/15';
var score:Number=0;

function getEggs(event:Event):void {

    if(event.target.hitTestObject(MovieClip(root).newCrag) && event.target is egg_mc) {

        sndEgg.play();

        if(event.target.stage) {
            event.target.parent.removeChild(event.target);
        } 

        // Increase score
        score++;
        newScore.score_txt.text = "" + score + '/15';

    }

}
```

I am trying to refer to the number value of the score using if statements. I need to change the speed variables based off the number that is inside the score box.

```
var speed:Number

if(score > 10 || score == 10) {
    speed=20;
    trace("speed3");
} else if(score > 5 || score == 5 && score < 10) {
    speed=18;
    trace("speed2");
} else {
    speed=14;
    trace("speed1");
}
```

However, this part of the code is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Wade

Comment: Is score defined in the same scope as the 2nd code-block you posted? i haven't worked with as3 in a while

Comment: ya, all in the root timeline, same frame, not within a function.

Comment: how does your score check get executed? If it's all on one frame it will run only once (the first time) Or if it's 'enter frame' it will reset the score to 0 each iteration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var speed:Number; //you missed a semicolon here
 if (score>=10) {
  speed=20;
  trace("speed3");
 } else if (score>=5) {//no need to test twice for <10
  speed=18;
  trace("speed2");
 } else {
  speed=14;
  trace("speed1");
 }
```

Or (for interest only), all on one line:

```
speed = (score>=10)?20:((score>=5)?18:14);// no points for readability!
```